# How to retrieve data from post request in Django?

Tags: django

I have the following post request:

```
$('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
                    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                    console.log(data.fields.name)
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "distribute/",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {name:"data.fields.name"},
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        }
                    });
             } );
```

This is my distribute method in views.py:

```
def distribute(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        print request
    return HttpResponse("")
```

When I look at the output of **print request** I don't see the data that I sent at all. How can I access the data that I sent in the request?

Comment: The data is stored as a `QueryDict` in `request.POST`.

Comment: I tried it, but it's empty

Comment: Can you print *exactly* what is printed?

Comment: I solved it by using JSON.stringify() in data, and then changing the content type to application/json. In my views.py I accessed the data as request.body

Comment: but this looks like "circumventing" the problem. It also means that you will need to make an AJAX equivalent for every view, which is not advisable. So it is probably better to solve the *core* problem.

Comment: According to the documentation, the data that  appear in request.POST is only Form data, but the data that I need to send is not form data.

Comment: well in fact it is: there is no concept of a "form" in HTTP: a HTTP request simply has a header and body, and sends to a URL. It ships GET parameters in the URL, POST parameters in the header, and optionally (although not very popular) there is data in the body. The point is that *typically* data in a *HTML* form ships as POST data. This process is then typically "mimicked" by AJAX. Otherwise one has to define different views to carry out the same task, which would violate the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.POST.get("name")`. Also, should it be:

```
 data: {"name":data.fields.name}
```

instead of:

```
 data: {name:"data.fields.name"}
```

?